# Send parameter to url in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having trouble sending a parameter into a url of another page. I'm new to coding in PHP so I do not really know how to get this through, already did some research on this about the $_GET method, but its still not working.

Code in 1st page:

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='application_desktop.php?id='". $temp ."'>" . $row['appl_nric_date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['applicant_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['nric'] . "</td><td>" . $row['application_date'] . "</a></td></tr>";
```

where `$temp` is the parameter I want to pass to the url.

Code in 2nd page:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$applicants = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblapplication WHERE appl_nric_date = $id");
//$applicants = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblapplication WHERE appl_nric_date = 10");
```

The sql query returns error that the $id is null, and the url doesn't display the id.

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Yes I understand that, Im just using code that my supervisor used and is working on his side. Thanks @Obsidian Age

Comment: If your supervisor is using the MySQL wrapper, I'd recommend telling him to switch over immediately. You might even get some bonus points ;)

Comment: Well honestly, I did try using mysqli previously with another part of the code, but it did not work, so i guess im still using versions before 5.5 @Obsidian Age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this on your html line

```
echo "<tr><td><a href=" . 'application_desktop.php?id=' . $temp . ">" . $row['appl_nric_date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['applicant_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['nric'] . "</td><td>" . $row['application_date'] . "</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code to see what it output:

```
// Make some sample data
$row = [
'appl_nric_date' => '9999-99-99',
'applicant_name' => 'some-applicant',
'nric' => 'wtf-is-an-nric',
'application_date' => '8888-99-00'
];

$temp = 'something';

echo "<tr><td><a href='application_desktop.php?id='". $temp ."'>" 
    . $row['appl_nric_date'] 
    . "</td><td>" 
    . $row['applicant_name'] 
    . "</td><td>" 
    . $row['nric'] 
    . "</td><td>" 
    . $row['application_date'] . "</a></td></tr>";

echo PHP_EOL;
```

This is what it outputs:

```
<tr><td><a href='application_desktop.php?id='something'>9999-99-99</td><td>some-applicant</td><td>wtf-is-an-nric</td><td>8888-99-00</a></td></tr>
```

The use of single quotes is not right. Remove the single quote after `id=`.

Looks like you are not nesting your html elements correctly. You place the opening A tag inside the first TD but then you close that TD without closing the A tag.

In order to debug what you are doing this in the browser, then the address bar where the url lives should show the parameters that are sent to the destination page. You can just look at that to verify that it sent what you intended.

In the destination page, you can add the following to debug:

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($_GET) ?>
</pre>
```

The above will let you see what you are getting from the first page.

Comment: Thanks for answering, noted.